# Extract a string from string, choosing the method

Tags: powershell

I have a string which looks like this:
[Error] Failed to process site: https://xxxxxxxxx/teams/**xxxxxx**. The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

The challenge is to extract highlighted part of this string.

Tried some split operation but without any success.

Comment: You forgot to post your coding attempts.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-match` operator to perform a [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions) search for the URL, then extract the matched string value:

```
# define input string
$errorString = '[Error] Failed to process site: https://some.domain.tld/teams/xxxxxx. The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.'

# define regex pattern for a URL followed by a literal dot
$urlFollowedByDotPattern = 'https?://(?:www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)(?=\.)'

# perform match comparison
if($errorString -match $urlFollowedByDotPattern){
    # extract the substring containing the URL matched by the pattern
    $URL = $Matches[0]

    # remove everything before the last slash
    $pathSuffix = $URL -replace '^.*/'
}
```

If the URL was found, the `$pathSuffix` variable now contains the trailing `xxxxxx` part

Answer (score 1):

To offer a concise alternative to [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72982839/45375) using the regex-based 
[`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator):

**`-replace` can be special-cased for *substring extraction*** by:

- formulating a regex that matches the *entire* input string
- using a capture group (`(...)`) inside that regex to capture the substring of interest and using that as the replacement string; e.g., `$1` in the replacement string refers to what the first capture group captured.

```bash
$str = '[Error] Failed to process site: https://xxxxxxxxx/teams/xxxxxx. The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.'

$str -replace '.+https://.+/([^/]+)\..+', '$1' # -> 'xxxxxx'
```

For an explanation of the regex and the option to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/yyISj4/1).

Note:

- If the regex does *not* match, the whole input string is returned as-is.
- If you'd rather return an *empty string* in that case, use a technique suggested by [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42): append `|.*` to the regex, which alternatively (`|`), if the original regex didn't match, *unconditionally* matches the whole input string with `.*`, in which case - since no capture group is then used - `$1` evaluates to the empty string as the effective return value:

  ```bash
  # Note the addition of |.*
  'this has no URL' -replace '.+https://.+/([^/]+)\..+|.*', '$1' # -> ''
  ```

  - [regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/tGc2wt/1).

---

If such a regex is too mind-bending, you can try **a multi-step approach that combines [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) and [`-like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-like)**:

```bash
$str = '[Error] Failed to process site: https://xxxxxxxxx/teams/xxxxxx. The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.'

# -> 'xxxxxx'
# Note the line continuations (` at the very end of the lines)
# required to spread the command across multiple lines for readability.
(
  -split $str        <#  split into tokens by whitespace #> `
  -like 'https://*'  <# select the token that starts with 'https://' #> `
  -split '/'         <# split it into URL components by '/' #>
)[-1]?.TrimEnd('.')  <# select the last component and trim the traiing "." #>
```

Note:

- The use `?.`, the null-conditional member-access operator, prevents a statement-terminating error if no token of interest is found (`$null` is returned instead), but it requires *PowerShell (Core) 7.1+*.
- In earlier versions or alternatively, you can replace `?.TrimEnd('.')` with `-replace '\.$'`, which defaults to an *empty string* instead.

Comment: Thanks, @zett42, that is clever too - I've updated the answer to include your solution.